# USB headset doesn't connect automatically when plugged-in in CentOS 6.5

Tags: linux, audio, centos

The USB headsets are not automatically selected when plugged-out and back in, it must be manually done each time.

So far, I have tried to modify /etc/pulse/default.pa to include a module I have copied from a Suse 12.3 machine, as there wasn't one in CentOS:

.ifexists module-switch-on-connect.so
.nofail
load-module module-switch-on-connect
.fail
.endif

module-switch-on-connect.so is the copied module.

It doesn't work.

Any ideas on how to solve the issue?